# How conductive must be capacitor plates?

Tags: capacitance

So from equations I see that a capacitors capacitance increases with area of conductive plates and dielectrical value of dielectric between the plates. It also increases with decrease of distance between two plates.

But I can't find anywhere how the conductivity of plates effects the capacitance and other phenomena connected to capacitors.

Because for my aplication it would be ideal to have plates made out of resistor. But they need to be conductive. So the question is HOW conductive and HOW conductivity of plates effects the capacitor.

Comment: Resistive plates would, to first order, be modeled by adding an equivalent series resistor (in series with) an ideal capacitor which will give non-zero time constant and energy dissipation.  But doesn't the answer to your question depend on the details of your application, e.g., the typical charging/discharging current?

Comment: The capacitor should work in alternating magnetic field. But I don't want the capacitor plates to be inducing eddy currents because of it. So I'm now just thinking about making plates less conductive and how it would effect the capacitance. And let's leave interference out of this because I'm only interested in a thought experiment from which I might learn something. But if you must know, the capacitor Will be used for a sensor of capacitance which changes according to the environment.